# Symmetric vs. Asymmetric encryption for encrypting images on Android

Tags: android, encryption

I am trying to create an Android app that encrypts data on-the-fly and write it to storage. Already implemented the app with no encryption, checked 100+ examples/posts of encryption on stackoverflow but couldn't decide which method to use.

At first thought of of using AES and did some googling to find how secure it is. Entering 16 or 32 character (better security, i hope)  passwords every time doesn't seems convenient. As an alternative Asymmetric encryption came to mind. Encrypt with one key and decrypt with the other, so that i can leave the key used for encryption in the memory and use the other key only when data needs to be decrypted (like offline on a PC, or on another app).

Files that will be encrypted will be mostly images,video, audio recordings, office documents.

Does second method leaves any vulnerabilities? Between AES and RSA which one is better if i need to balance for speed and security. Data isn't anything top-secret, just need to prevent falling to wrong hands. The device is not encrypted, running KitKat. How well does both method stands against some kind of attack ?

EDIT: Describing two methods.

Method 1: Use password based AES encryption, manually enter 16/32 character password upon application start, clear the password after sometime/certain triggers from the memory. Enter password again when required.

Method 2: Use private/public key based RSA encryption. Leave one key, the one used for encryption on the device. Use the other key during decryption, which is scarcely performed.

Answer (score 3):

This question is somewhat difficult to answer since you haven't actually described any methods, you've just named two encryption algorithms.  If implemented **properly**, both algorithms are more than secure for your needs.

It is important to remember that RSA can encrypt data no longer than its key length (minus some for padding), so in most cases RSA alone is not enough.

If you are simply encrypting information on a single device and want the **user** in control of when it is encrypted and decrypted, e.g. with a password, you can use PBKDF2 to derive a key of x length (e.g. for AES256, 32 bytes) with a password string as input.

Don't bother using RSA if you aren't going to take advantage of its asymmetric properties.  In most cases (but not all) RSA is redundant if no server or additional party is involved.

You don't describe your problem much, but if it was me, I'd use AES.

When using AES, please keep the following in mind:

- **Never** use ECB mode.
- **Never** use plain ASCII bytes as a key.  You should use PBKDF2 or similar to derive a key, normally 100,000 rounds is good.
- **Always** use a secure RNG to create your IV (if your cipher mode uses one, some, like CTR, use a nonce instead, but the concept is pretty much the same).
- **Always** remember that AES **does not** ensure integrity.  Use a MAC to detect changes in the ciphertext before decrypting.

Comment: @ Luke Park : Thank you for your answer. I implemented AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding with PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 with a 256 bit key and 1000 rounds. Takes less than 2 seconds for a 5 MB file. Needs to tidy up the code/logic/flow and do a precise measurement.

Comment: @RaghavPete Glad you've got it working.  However, 1000 rounds isn't nearly enough for PBKDF2 anymore.  These days you should be around the ~100,000 mark at least.

Comment: @ Luke Park : I was planning for 10,000 rounds. Need to see how much extra time is required for additional rounds.